# Inncorect image store Laravel 5.1 on host

Tags: php, laravel

When I was uploading images on my localhost everything worked fine. Now when I uploaded my website to server the image uploads and in DB it shows this: `/tmp/phptDVxoK`

This is my controller code:

```
public function themeStore(ThemeRequest $request)
{

    $theme = Theme::create($request->all());
    $theme->slug = str_slug($theme->title);


if(Input::hasfile('image'))
{
$request->file('image')->move(public_path('images/themes/'), $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName());

$theme->image = 'images/themes/' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
}    


    Auth::user()->theme()->save($theme);
    $theme->category()->attach($request->input('categories_list'));

    flash()->success('Dizainas buvo sėkmingai patalpintas į dizainų parduotuvę.');

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Does anybody knows the solution ?

Comment: Could you add some debug information in your question? Like the result of `dump($request->file('image'))` on line 10 and `dump($theme->image)` on line 13? Also, is your `images/themes/` folder writable on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use both `Input` and `$request`, but I tested in [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), something `Input` can get value, but `$request` can't and opposite (depend of input type: json, text,..).

If this condition `if(Input::hasfile('image'))` return `true`, please change syntax:

```
{
Input::file('image')->move(public_path('images/themes/'), Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName());

$theme->image = 'images/themes/' . Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

Or check `hasFile` with `$request`: `if ($request->hasFile('image')) {}`

See more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests).